# distance minimizing geodesics on hyperbolic surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Suppose $X = X_r \times X_{\theta}$ is a product manifold with $X_r = ( 0 , \infty)$ and $X_{\theta} = S^1$ be the unit circle , introduce the following metric on $X$, given by $dr^2 + (cos \hspace{0.01 cm} hr) ^2 d{\theta}^2$, for those who are familiar with infinite area hyperbolic surfaces , this is an infinite area funnel. Let $d_X$ denote the associated metric distance on X.

Suppose $\pi: X \longrightarrow X_r$ denote the canonical projection onto the first coordinate.

Let $\gamma(t)$ be a unit speed geodesic on $X$, which satisfies the assumption that $\pi(\gamma(t)) \longrightarrow \infty$ as $t \longrightarrow \infty$

I am interested in either a proof or a counter example for the following claim.

There exists a $t_0 \gg 0 $ such that $d_X(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2)) = |t_2-t_1|$ , for $t_1,t_2 \geq  t_0$

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to asking whether there are geodesics on the funnel that wrap around $S^1$ infinitely often? So the answer to your question would be no with the flat metric, but I don't have a good enough intuition for geodesics on the hyperbolic funnel.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for, in the case of a hyperbolic funnel if a geodesic wrap around $S^1$ infinitely many times, but even in the flat case for a cylinder $X = X_r \times X_{\theta}$ , with the flat metric $dr^2+d{\theta}^2$ , there are geodesics in the shape of a helix that that wrap around $S^1$ infinitely often, so the claim that I am trying to prove does not hold in the flat case.